# Detail transfer from high poly to low poly mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I saw that people in different tutorials transfer details from a high poly to a low poly mesh by overlapping them and adding a multires and a shrinkwrap modifier to the lowpoly mesh.

Why do they do that? Is it that after the detail transfer if I turn the subdivisions on the lowpoly multires back to zero the model looks better than before even though it has the same vertex count?

Comment: Hello, maybe link one of these tutorials?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQfFlzHJJ88&t=1371s here for example at the chapter that starts at ~ min 32

Comment: Yes not sure why he does that instead of continuing to sculpt the hight poly